# Need help adding WHERE clause in pre-written SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

Preface: my SQL is rudimentary. I received a SQL query from a vendor, it selects and exports every single employee comment and other data from a few different DBs as CSV meant for import, it was written by them but they're not helping with this request. The query is pulling so much data it makes a large time consuming file for import. So I want to add to / modify the query to have a "WHERE date > whateverdate" to narrow my results to recent data. For example, I want to pull only comments entered in the past 2 days.

The column I'm looking to add the clause for is the column "A.CMS502", defined as datetime. I believe this is the only relevant column in this query. An example date in this column is "2003-10-06 17:05:21.000". I am using SQL Server 2008 if it helps. Is it possible here? Thank you.

```
SELECT 
    'ID,Acct/LnNbr,NoteCreatedDate,CollectorId,ApplytoAll,Note'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ID + ',' + ID + ',' + NoteCreatedDate + ',' + CollectorId + ',' + 'No' + ',' + Note
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,LEN(A.CMS301),1) = 'S' 
                 THEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,1,LEN(A.CMS301) - 1) 
                 ELSE A.CMS301 
         END + '-' + 
         CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,LEN(A.CMS301),1) = 'S' 
                 THEN 'S' ELSE 'L'
         END AS [ID],
         REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.CMS501, 10), '-', '') AS [NoteCreatedDate],
         CASE WHEN U.CMS1201 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN U.CMS1205 + ' ' + U.CMS1204 
                 ELSE (SELECT CMS1205 + ' ' + CMS1204 FROM sysUSER WHERE CMS1201 = 'PSUSER')
         END AS CollectorId,
         CAST(A.CMS512 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Note]
     FROM 
         ACTIVITY AS A
     LEFT JOIN 
         sysUSER AS U ON A.CMS503 = U.CMS1201
     WHERE 
         A.CMS504 NOT IN (411,500,511,711,804,900,901,903,907,2000,999777)
         AND A.CMS504 NOT BETWEEN 1102 AND 1199) AS S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will output last 2 days.

```
SELECT 'ID,Acct/LnNbr,NoteCreatedDate,CollectorId,ApplytoAll,Note'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID + ',' + ID + ',' + NoteCreatedDate + ',' + CollectorId + ',' + 'No' + ',' + Note
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,LEN(A.CMS301),1) = 'S' THEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,1,LEN(A.CMS301) - 1) ELSE A.CMS301 END
+ '-' + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(A.CMS301,LEN(A.CMS301),1) = 'S' THEN 'S' ELSE 'L'
END AS [ID]
,REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,A.CMS501,10),'-','') AS [NoteCreatedDate]
,CASE WHEN U.CMS1201 IS NOT NULL THEN U.CMS1205 + ' ' + U.CMS1204 ELSE
(SELECT CMS1205 + ' ' + CMS1204 FROM sysUSER WHERE CMS1201 = 'PSUSER')
END AS CollectorId
,CAST(A.CMS512 AS nvarchar(max)) AS [Note]
FROM ACTIVITY AS A
LEFT JOIN sysUSER AS U
ON A.CMS503 = U.CMS1201
WHERE A.CMS504 NOT IN (411,500,511,711,804,900,901,903,907,2000,999777)
AND A.CMS504 NOT BETWEEN 1102 AND 1199

AND A.CMS502 >= DATEADD(D, -2, GETDATE())

) AS S
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and worked perfectly. Thanks for making it so easy, I was over complicating it for sure, and also had no idea where to put it (table joining is still Latin to me). I can't believe my vendor said they couldn't do it.